# Laravel middleware different method if no access token found

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-passport

I'm newbie for Laravel passport. What I want to achieve is able to verify whether there is access token pass in by user.

I want to call @index route when there are access token found,
call @indexTest route when no access token is found.

Do I have to create custom middleware for this case?
Thanks.

In api.php

```js
/**
 * Category
 */
Route::resource('categoriesbranches', 'Category\CategoryBranchController@index', ['only' => ['index']])->middleware('client.credentials');
Route::resource('categoriesbranches', 'Category\CategoryBranchController@indexTest');
```

In CategoryBranchController.php

```js
    // public function __construct()
    // {
    //     $this->middleware('client.credentials')->only(['index']);
    // }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //different action
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function indexTest()
    {
        //different action
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a middleware and check for access token and then redirect the call where you want, if it has the access token you just `$next($request)`

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a middleware and add a before middleware method to check if the request has token even before any routing. 
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware